# How to find ratio value between two consecutive dates

Tags: sql-server, date, group-by, aggregate-functions

Given a table which consists of:
ID_User, Date

I'd like to find the ratio between every two consecutive days,
The ratio between the **same people** who attended day x and day x+1.
i'll give an example:

let's say :

```
Bill 12155 2018-05-01
Jim 52135 2018-05-01
Homer 52135 2018-05-01
Jecki 56135 2018-05-01
Michael 45644 2018-05-02
Jim 52135 2018-05-02
Jessy 45645 2018-05-02
Homer 52135 2018-05-02
```

So the ratio would be 2/4 = 0.5

I tried resolving it on my own for the last day but had some struggles.
I started by grouping by date:

```
Select Date, ID_USER
GROUP BY DATE, ID_USER
ORDER BY DATE, ID_USER
```

can someone please give me some pointers,

Thank you all!

Comment: What are `2` and `4` in  `2/4 = 0.5`? Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem with your sample data... 2 users (Jim and Homer) both have the same ID (52135) so grouping by ID gets messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.[Date], 
      ( CONVERT(decimal, SUM(CASE WHEN t2.[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) / COUNT(t1.[ID]) ) AS [Ratio]
FROM @YourTbl t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @YourTbl t2 ON t2.[ID] = t1.[ID] AND t2.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, t1.[Date]) 
GROUP BY t1.[Date]
```

Group your data by the first `Date` (in your sample, `05-01-2018`).

Then, self-join the table by doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so you have the full list of data and a second list of only the data where the same user (based on ID) is in the data again for the next day (`DATEADD( DAY, 1, ... )`).

Then you can tell if any user has attended two days in a row based on a given date by checking any field in `t2` to be `NULL`.

To get a ratio of Users who attended `t1.[Date]` and the next date `t2.[Date]`, total up the users in `t2` where the `ID` is `NOT NULL` and divide it by the total count of users for that day in `t1`. Now, since `SUM` returns an `INT` in this case and you need a decimal, `CONVERT` the `SUM` to `DECIMAL` and you will get a decimal number.

Here are the results for your sample data: Note: After changing the ID of either Jim or Homer since they originally had the same ID.

```
Date          Ratio
2018-05-01    0.50000000000
2018-05-02    0.00000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The self-join solution is valid. You might try this approach as well:

```
with data as (
    select "date",
        case when dateadd(day, 1, "date") = 
            lead("date") over (partition by id order by "date")
                then 1 end as returned
    from T
)
select "date", count(returned) * 1. / count(*) as ratio
from data
group by "date";
```

If you want to eliminate the final date since it's always zero, you could easily add `case when "date" <> max("date") over () then 1 end as notfinal` and filter based on that.

https://rextester.com/HHL82126